# Computation of a projection onto orthogonal complement

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, projection

In $\mathbb{R}^4$, let $\underline{a} = (1, 2,-2, 0)$ ,  $\underline{b} = (2, 1, 0, 4)$ and  $\underline{c} = (5, 7, 3, 2)$. I want to determine that the orthogonal
projection of $\underline{c}$ on $< \underline{a}, \underline{b} >^\perp$ is $(2,4,5,-2)$.

We already know that $\underline{a}$ and $\underline{b}$ are orthogonal to this space, so they are precisely the vectors that we need. I tried using:

$$C_{proj}=c- \frac{a\cdot c}{|a|^2}a  -\frac{b\cdot c}{|b|^2}b$$

And then I get $$(5,7,3,2)-\frac{13}{9}(1,2,-2,0)-\frac{25}{21}(2,1,0,4) \neq (2,4,5,-2)$$
Is there something wrong in my method of orthogonal projection?
It would be very conventient if these fators would be $-1$ and $-1$ instead.

Comment: Check your calculations. $a\cdot c$ is not $9$.

Comment: The correct orthogonal projection is $(2,4,5,-2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal vectors and $S:=\mathrm{span}\{x,y\}$ is the subspace spanned by $x$ and $y$, then 
$$
(*)\quad \mathrm{proj}_{S^\perp}(z) = z - \frac{z\cdot x}{|x|^2}x - \frac{z\cdot y}{|y|^2}y
$$
(where $|x|$ is the length of vector $x$) is the projection of the vector $z$ onto the subspace $S^\perp$.

In your case, $\underline{a}$ and $\underline{b}$ are not orthogonal, so we find another vector $\underline{d}\in \mathrm{span}\{\underline{a}, \underline{b}\}$ which is perpendicular to $\underline{a}$.
$$
\mathrm{proj}_{\underline{a}^\perp}\left(\underline{b}\right) = \underline{b} - \frac{\underline{b}\cdot \underline{a}}{|\underline{a}|^2}\underline{a} 
$$
$$
= (2, 1, 0, 4) - \frac{(2, 1, 0, 4)\cdot (1, 2, -2, 0)}{|(1, 2, -2, 0)|} (1, 2, -2, 0)
$$
$$
= \left(\frac{14}{9},\frac{1}{9},\frac{8}{9},4\right).
$$
So, $\underline{d}=(14,1,8, 36)$ is in $S$ and it is perpendicular to $\underline{a}$.  We can now apply formula (*) to compute the projection of $\underline{c}$ on to $S^\perp$.
$$
\mathrm{proj}_{S^\perp}\left(\underline{c}\right) = \underline{c} - \frac{\underline{c}\cdot \underline{a}}{|\underline{a}|^2}\underline{a} - \frac{\underline{c}\cdot \underline{d}}{|\underline{d}|^2}\underline{d}
$$
$$
= (5, 7, 3, 2)- 13/9 (1, 2, -2, 0) - 173/1557 (14, 1, 8, 36)
$$
$$
= (2, 4, 5, -2).
$$

Comment: Thanks, I tend to make small computational errors rather quickly. This allowed me to check the numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Your method would work indeed if $a$ and $b$ were orthogonal, but they aren't. Replace $b$ with $b^\star=(14,1,8,36)$. Then $\operatorname{span}\bigl(\{a,b^\star\}\bigr)=\operatorname{span}\bigl(\{a,b\}\bigr)$ (because $b^\star=9b-4a$), but $a.b^\star=0$.